# which one of the following expressions is faster to determine index of minimum element in a list?

Tags: list, python-3.x, indexing, minimum

```
 >>> l=[1,2,3]
 >>> l.index(min(l))
 >>> 0
 >>> from operator import itemgetter
 >>> min(enumerate(l),key=itemgetter(1))[0]
 >>> 0
```

need to use this repeatedly inside a loop of 10,000 iterations , so which is more efficient

Comment: "need to use this repeatedly inside a loop of 10,000 iterations" - then you probably shouldn't be doing either of these things. You probably need to change how you're organizing your data. Maybe you need a heap or something.

Comment: Profile them and find out for yourself.

Comment: @user2357112 my main algorithm already uses a heap I am using this in a heuristic function which is called in the main algorithm and the min value gets added to the heap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have the same complexity of O(n). You can check the cpu time to see which one suits you best